# A question from Aaronson 2004 paper

Tags: mathematics, pauli-gates, stabilizer-code, clifford-group

In Aaronson's paper about the efficient simulation of a stabilizer circuit
(https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.70.052328),
I have a problem with finding the reason why the following statement holds.
Restating the statement in the end of the 4th page of the paper,
Let $\{R_{h+n}\}$ with $h=1...n$ are the Pauli stabilizer of a state $|{\psi}\rangle$.
If $Z_a$ commutes with all of $\{R_{h+n}\}$, then
$$\sum_{h=1}^n c_hR_{n+h} = \pm Z_a$$
for a unique choice of $c_1 \dots c_n \in {0,1}$.

But for $|\psi\rangle=|11\rangle$, we have stabilizers of ${II, ZZ}$ only, and its combination can make neither of single-qubit $Z$ gate.

If I have misunderstood, I will be very appreciative if you can correct it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terms $II$ and $ZZ$ do not uniquely specify the state $|11\rangle$ because you could equally have the state $|00\rangle$. Indeed, you should not include the identity term in your stabilizer. Thus, you need to add a second term, which could be either $-ZI$ or $-IZ$. Either way, you can easily see how to make a product $-ZI$ out of your stabilizers.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to check the sign of the operators. That is a good point. However, I still wonder why the equation in my question holds. Can you give proof of it, please?